# Pyarrow keeps converting string to binary using Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache, pandas, parquet

I am trying to convert a csv file to parquet using pandas and pyarrow in python2.7.

I am having an issue with converting string to string from the pa.Table.from_pandas(df) conversion. It keeps converting the data type to 'binary' and this makes AWS Glue very unhappy.

I have attempted a customized schema it will not work.

```
fields = []
for name, type in dtypes.items():
        fields.append(pa.field(name, type))
my_schema = pa.schema(fields)
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file), delimiter="\t")
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
```

Previously was specifying the datatype when reading in the csv, that did not work either. Also tried replace_schema_metadata() but that doesn't do much as it isn't the actual schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2's `str` type is actually the same content as Parquet's definition of BINARY, thus all columns with `str` objects will be saved as `binary`. In Python 3, they should then be correctly loaded as `bytes`. To store columns as string / `UTF-8` in Parquet, you need to convert the column to `unicode` objects.

Comment: Thanks! That was the one thing I didn't try, so adding encoding='utf8' when reading in the dataframe helped the schema convert strings to strings!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

`df = df.astype(unicode)`

Answer (score -1):

@Maddy Schiappa, also please note that since you had mentioned AWS Glue, only pure python libraries are supported currently. "

> You can use Python extension modules and libraries with your AWS Glue
>   ETL scripts as long as they are written in pure Python. C libraries
>   such as pandas are not supported at the present time, nor are
>   extensions written in other languages.

- Refer : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question as the code is executed outside of Glue. `pyarrow` creates files outside of the Glue environment that are then later ingested by Glue but using different libraries (probably parquet-mr).